# Empty page displaying in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, template, php-5.4

I am new to magento, I have created my custom module which is page. In `page/html/header.phtml` I add my custom content but it's displaying empty page. and I have set my package in `system/configuration/design/package = easylife`.

my code is

**magento\app\etc\modules\Easylife_All.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Page>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page/>
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Page>        
    </modules>
</config>
```

and

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\Page\etc\config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Easylife_Page>
                <version>1.6.0.1</version>
            </Easylife_Page>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <page>
                        <file before="Mage_Page">page.xml</file>
                    </page>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
        <stores>
            <admin>
                <design>
                    <theme>
                        <default>easylife</default>
                    </theme>
                </design>
            </admin>
        </stores>
    </config>
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\default\layout\page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
            <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

                    <!-- Custom COde -->
                    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name><params/></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/cf.js</name><params/></action>

                </block>
            </block>
    </default>

</layout>
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\default\template\page\html\header.phtml**

```
  <?php

    ?>
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header">
            <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
                <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
            <?php else:?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
            <?php endif?>
            <div class="quick-access">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
                <!--?php Mage::log((array)$this->getChildHtml('topLinks')) ?-->
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
                <!-- Custom Code -->
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_cartheader') ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

I request **//localhost/magento/index.php/**  page but it's displaying empty page.

why it's displaying empty page?

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are going about this the wrong way. From what I think your aim is:

1. Add some custom js files,
2. Change a single template slightly,

I would suggest just creating a local.xml file in your theme, rather than creating a complete theme an completely replacing the standard page.xml. The fact that you are replacing all the contents of the page.xml file is why you get a blank page.

If you create a local.xml that looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/jquery.js</name>
                <params/>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/cf.js</name>
                <params/>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>path/to/your/new/header.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Without creating a completely new theme when one is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some error on the page. Go to index.php and uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Also go to `magento/var/log/` and check log files.

Comment: @Oleksiisvarychevskyi, I uncommented `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` this and `magento/var/log/system.log` file there is no errors I got. what happend can you suggest me? my code is correct or not?

Comment: Can you give me a example of code for override Page module from custom package?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a name conflict between **Mage_Page** and your **Easylife_Page**. Both use `Page` as a module name which will lead to issues.

From what I can see you're trying to add some CSS and some edits to `header.phtml` which can be done without an extension.

In your package/templates `layout` directory create a `local.xml` and add the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
      <reference name="head">
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name><params/></action>
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/cf.js</name><params/></action>
      </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

and in the `template` directory add the file `page/html/header.phtml` with your custom html code.